# Susan Corner Detector implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection

I have not understood the code and the way function is handled..

can you  elaborate the function declaration

```
fun = @(img) susanFun(img);
map = nlfilter(img,maskSz,fun);
```

Also in susan corner detector we have only 2 threshold values.. "t and g".. but here we have "thGeo,thGeo1,thGeo2,thT,thT1"

I am not able to understand the method employed here:

```
function [ map r c ] = susanCorner( img )
%SUSAN Corner detection using SUSAN method.
%   [R C] = SUSAN(IMG)  Rows and columns of corner points are returned.


maskSz = [7 7];
fun = @(img) susanFun(img);
map = nlfilter(img,maskSz,fun);
[r c] = find(map);

end

function res = susanFun(img)
% SUSANFUN  Determine if the center of the image patch IMG
%   is corner(res = 1) or not(res = 0)


mask = [...
    0 0 1 1 1 0 0
    0 1 1 1 1 1 0
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    0 1 1 1 1 1 0
    0 0 1 1 1 0 0];

% uses 2 thresholds to distinguish corners from edges
thGeo = (nnz(mask)-1)*.2;
thGeo1 = (nnz(mask)-1)*.4;
thGeo2 = (nnz(mask)-1)*.4;
thT = .07;
thT1 = .04;

sz = size(img,1);
usan = ones(sz)*img(round(sz/2),round(sz/2));

similar = (abs(usan-img)<thT);
similar = similar.*mask;
res = sum(similar(:));
if res < thGeo
    dark = nnz((img-usan<-thT1).*mask);
    bright = nnz((img-usan>thT1).*mask);
    res = min(dark,bright)<thGeo1 && max(dark,bright)>thGeo2;

else
    res = 0;
end

end
```

Comment: Since all the code here is just copied from http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30789-corner-detection-using-susan-operator/content/susanCorner.m, wouldn't it be best to just ask the author (whose address you can find via that page).

Answer (score 0):

```
fun = @(img) susanFun(img);
map = nlfilter(img,maskSz,fun);
```

means

- `fun` is a handle (or pointer) to a function.
- `@(img)` says `fun` takes an argument called `img`.
- `susanFun(img)` is the body of `fun`

`nlfilter` is passed the function handle `fun` and can call it.
In fact, it will apply `fun` with the parameter `img` as each 7x7 sliding block of the image `img`.
Note that the name `img` is overloaded here: it is name name of a variable holding an image, and it is the name of the parameter of `fun`.

See [function_handle (@)](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html)