# Circular mask over each pixel in image

Tags: matlab, mask

Wondering if anyone can help me get started. I want to put a circular over each pixel in an image (gray scale) using matlab. In the circular mask I want to test every pixel against the center pixel in the circle. To see if the pixel intensity is higher or lower than the center pixel.

The mask I want should have 37 pixels (included the center pixel).

Should I create a mask like this

```
mask = [...
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0];
```

Or is there a better way? And how should I place it over each pixel and do the test what I want?

Any help is much appreciated:)

Comment: No, assuming you want whole pixels, you can't get a very circular circle out of a 7x7 mask.

Comment: I want a mask with 37 pixels or with a radius equal to 3.4. I just thought a mask like that would make it easier to calculate the pixels with center?

Comment: I'm really unclear as to what you're asking. What sort of operations are you trying to do? What is wrong with the current mask that you want to do differently?

Comment: I'm asking how I can move the mask over every pixel in an image. And use the mask to compare intensity of the center pixel with the rest of the pixels in the mask. 
The center pixel will be the pixel the mask moves to. So the first center pixel is 1,1 and than 1,2 and so on.

Comment: "Compare the intensity of the center pixel to the rest of the pixels in the mask." What exactly is the result of this comparison at each pixel? Is it a scalar? Is it a vector of 36 values? Is the value the difference of the pixel values, or the sign of the difference? p.s. It helps if you ping someone when you respond to them like @beaker. That way they get notified that you've responded rather than relying on them happening to drop by a couple of days later.

Comment: @beaker sorry for late reply. I want intensity of the tested pixel minus the intensity of center pixel of the mask. If this difference is lower than a set threshold, I want to have 1, if not 0.
I basically trying to make the SUSAN feature detector, if you are familier with it. I know about the one at mathworks. But that program uses several thresholds. I just want two.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753541/susan-corner-detector-implementation) implementation seems to use only 2 thresholds.

Comment: @beaker If I understand correctly that implementation use 4 different thresholds. 2 geometric thresholds (thGeo and thGeo1/2) and 2 thresholds (tTh and tTh1). SUSAN use only 1 geometric threshold and 1 intensity threshold.

Comment: Okay, but it should be easy to remove one of each of those thresholds, right?

Answer (score 0):

The "rangefilt" function may be the one you are looking for. In this function, you will define a mask as you mentioned in your question. For each pixel in the image, it will return the range value (maximum value − minimum value).